# How i can binding data from summernote input with Angular 5

Tags: angular, summernote

How i can binding data from summernote input with Angular 5 ?

component.html

```
<textarea class="form-control" ngModel
         name="description"
         id="summernote"
         [(ngModel)]="learningunit.description"
         maxlength="10000" rows="50"></textarea>
```

component.ts

```
declare var $: any;

ngOnInit() {

  $('#summernote').summernote({
         height: 150,
      });
}
```

Comment: why would you use jquery in angular?

Comment: summernote  are required Jequery to work,

Comment: @ahmedhassan how did you add summernote in your component ?

Answer (score 0):

in component:

```
description;
```

in template

```
<textarea class="form-control" ngModel
         name="description"
         id="summernote"
         [(ngModel)]="description"
         maxlength="10000" rows="50"></textarea>
```

In real life

https://angular.io/docs

Comment: Well obviously it works just fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1cdk8 and yours *binding not working* is like recorded message.

Comment: i know, but the problem with summernote if i remove id='summernote'

Comment: create stackblitz